# Getting 503 Error for the Thread User 2000. Can anyone Help me what is the issues here

Tags: jmeter

> 

My scenario:

1. Thread group-1 400 users ram up time=5 secs
2. Thread group-2 400 users ram up time=5 secs
3. Thread group-3 400 users ram up time=5 secs
4. Thread group-4 400 users ram up time=5 secs
5. Thread group-5 400 users ram up time=5 secs

Now I wanted to run all threads together. so Total Users will be =2000. Can anyone help me per second how many users will get executed?.

why I'm getting 503 error for this test. I'm testing in a production environment and it is an Azure server.?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run 2000 users and your test duration is longer than the ramp-up time and there are no errors in the test causing failure to start a new thread or shutting it down then you will have 2000 concurrent users in 5 seconds.

If you're asking about how many requests per second you can get with 2000 users - we cannot answer as it mainly depends on your application response time, you can measure it using i.e. [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) or [Server Hits per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) listeners. See [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second) guide for more information if needed.

With regards to [HTTP Status Code 503](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503), as per description:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 503 Service Unavailable server error response code indicates that the server is not ready to handle the request.

> **Common causes are a server that is down for maintenance or that is overloaded.** This response should be used for temporary conditions and the Retry-After HTTP header should, if possible, contain the estimated time for the recovery of the service.

so most probably your server cannot handle such a load, you might want to check its logs and look at [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/overview) insights

Comment: Hi Dmitri T ,Thanks for  your info and I will look into that and  one doubt ,Whether I should increase the  Ramp Up time or not? Can you tell me is 2000 users taking 5 seconds ramp up time ?. Each Thread 5 seconds I have given, that means it should be executed within 25(5*5) or 5 Sec.